# jQuery UI: Specify location of internationalization files

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internationalization

I'm trying to set jQuery UI widgets up so that they can be internationalized.  I configured the datepicker as follows:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
```

And that triggers an attempted AJAX load, but it is using a URL that I don't want to use (`http://jqueryui.com/ui/i18n/ui.datepicker-fr.js`).

The URL it's trying to use seems to be incorrect, as it returns a Not Found error.  Besides, I have a local copy of the internationalization files and I want the datpicker to use that instead.

How do I configure where jQuery UI looks for its internationalization files?  i've not managed to find it in the documentation, and googling hasn't so far turned up anything useful yet.

**UPDATE**:  I have found that explicitly including the localization I want with a `<script>` tag works, it sets the date picker to the correct language.  However, according to the console, it still tries to load a translation file from jqueryui.com as well anyway.  I'd like to disable this if at all possible, because it's unnecessary and it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Are you loading jquery.js/jquery-ui.js files using a `<script>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI's `datepicker` plugin doesn't do XHR requests to bring in the i18n files.

It expects you to include the `<script>` tag to bring in the appropriate i18n file (for example http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js).

Live example http://jsbin.com/obixag/2.

I'm guessing that something else is doing the XHR.

Comment: I did eventually discover the <script> thing (it was documented on the core jQuery website instead of on jqueryui.com for some bizarre reason), but I'm honestly still at a loss as to why it's trying to access jqueryui.com for a translation file.  No digging around in the (admittedly convoluted) code base has turned up any requests to jqueryui.com yet.